# The best way for the Sql withthe laravel relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

- Manager hasOne Vendor
- Vendor hasMany Menu

And my route like this:

```
Route::get('vendor/{vid}/menu/{id}', 'MenuController@show');
```

I already wrote a query like this:

```
   $vendor = manager::where('status','>',0)
   ->with(['vendor' => function($query) use ($vid) {
        $query->where('id',$vid);
   }])->first()->vendor()->first();

   $menu= $vendor->menu()->where('id',$id)->first();

   return $menu;
```

I don`t Know the original Sql by this written ,but It seem query manay time,
is that any way for best efficacy?

Comment: you can create a wrapper function for that and only call that

Comment: why do you need the manager if you have the vendor id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the code, as it's equivalent of:

```
$menu = vendor::whereHas('manager', function($q) {
  $q->where('status', '>', 0);
})->findOrFail($vid)->menu()->find($id);
```

A call to **findOrFail()** will return an error if given vendor cannot be found. **whereHas** will make sure that related manager has correct status and **find()** will return a single model by default.